# How to get a list of installed android applications packages on chromebook?

Tags: android, google-chrome-os, chromebook

I know how to extract list of installed android apps in normal android device but is it possible to get list of installed android apps in chromebook?

Here is my code to get installed packages...

```
public static List<String> getInstalledAppsPackages(Context context) {
    List<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
            PackageInfo packageInfo = packs.get(i);
            packages.add(packageInfo.packageName);
        }
    }
    return packages;
}
```

Comment: When you ran your existing code to "extract list of installed android apps" on a Chromebook, what did you learn?

Comment: when i execute my existing code on chromebook its not returning the list of installed android app packages

Comment: Then perhaps provide a [mcve] showing your existing code. I haven't seen any problems with `PackageManager` in my testing to date.

Comment: i've just edited my question and now you can see my code to get installed apps packages

Answer (score 0):

I wrapped your code in an activity:

```
package com.commonsware.myapplication;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageInfo;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    for (String s : getInstalledAppsPackages(this)) {
      Log.e("20171004", s);
    }
  }

  public static List<String> getInstalledAppsPackages(Context context) {
    List<String> packages = new ArrayList<>();
    List<PackageInfo> packs = context.getPackageManager().getInstalledPackages(0);
    for (int i = 0; i < packs.size(); i++) {
      PackageInfo packageInfo = packs.get(i);
      packages.add(packageInfo.packageName);
    }

    return packages;
  }
}
```

I ran it on an Acer Chromebook R11 C738T, and I got:

```
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: android.autoinstalls.config.google.cheets
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.cts.priv.ctsshim
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.ext.services
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.providers.telephony
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.providers.calendar
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.providers.media
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.ext.shared
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.commonsware.android.envdump
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.wallpapercropper
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.view_downloads_handler
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.documentsui
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.default_intent
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.externalstorage
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.htmlviewer
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.rhmsoft.edit
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.providers.downloads
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.crash_collector
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.commonsware.myapplication
10-04 07:07:24.478 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.defcontainer
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.vending
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.pacprocessor
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.certinstaller
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.marvin.talkback
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.cast_receiver
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: android
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.camera2
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.file_system
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.backupconfirm
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.statementservice
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.providers.settings
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.printspooler
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.gms
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.ime
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.tts
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.apps.cloudprint
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.musicfx
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.webview
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.contacts
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.syncadapters.contacts
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.keychain
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.packageinstaller
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.gms
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.gsf
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.tts
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.commonsware.android.sensor.monitor
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.proxyhandler
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.feedback
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.printservice.recommendation
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.managedprovisioning
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.applauncher
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.gsf.login
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.accessibilityhelper
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.amaze.filemanager
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.storagemanager
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.settings
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.google.android.apps.work.clouddpc.arc
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.cts.ctsshim
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.intent_helper
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: org.chromium.arc.removablemediaprovider
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.vpndialogs
10-04 07:07:24.479 1512-1512/com.commonsware.myapplication E/20171004: com.android.shell
```

So, your code seems fine.

If this does not work on your specific Chrome OS device, there may be a device-specific bug. You could create a reproducible test case and file an issue on it.